# PhantomJS, Qunit, Grunt testing browser resize widgets

Tags: phantomjs, qunit, grunt-contrib-qunit

I've created a `jQuery UI Widget` that resizes a DIV/thing to fill up the browser screen. It all works fine but now I want to create `unit tests` for testing that it's resizing and keeping to boundaries etc.

I'm using `Grunt` with `grunt-contrib-qunit`, which uses `PhantomJS` to do tests but am now unsure how I can test browser resizing at this point as it's not possible via JS to resize a browser. Perhaps PhantomJS provides something that allows me to alter it at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Check [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) library. It allows you to control "browser" (which is PhantomJS actually).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to define the width and height of the chrome-less browser:

```
grunt.initConfig({
   qunit: {
      src: ['tests/test.html'],
      options: {
          page : {
              viewportSize : { width: 1280, height: 800 }
          }
      }
   },
});
```